# Why does Excel crash with OfficeJS task pane add-in with visibility property set to 1?

Tags: excel, office-js, add-in

Excel provides a setting in the taskpane.xml file which is called `visibility`. See  https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

If this parameter is set (in an Excel File to "1" - see code below) then Excel shows after opening the file a task pane which is called "New Office Add-in" and provides a button "Trust this add-in". Everything`s good until now.

But if I press this button, then Excel consistently crashes. The Excel Version we used for testing is the current O365 Version 1904.

We have tried it with different Excel Clients from Version 1903, 1904 and 1905 (Insider) on Windows 10 machines. It was always the same: Excel crashes when pressing the button "Trust this add-in". From our point of view this must be a bug of Excel and not of the add-in, but who knows?....

```
<wetp:taskpanes xmlns:wetp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/taskpanes/2010/11">
<wetp:taskpane dockstate="right" visibility="1" width="350" row="7">
<wetp:webextensionref xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:id="rId1"/>
</wetp:taskpane>
</wetp:taskpanes>
```

Does anyone know this problem, and maybe a solution in the settings of the XML-Files within the Excel File?

Comment: Can you please share your manifest and the code which you're referencing?

Comment: @MaviDomates I fixed an issue that had prevented the code from rendering in the question.

Comment: We found out what the crash causes: we use also the "AutoOpen"-Feature for the Add-In and had manually removed the Store-Information (store="") from the "webextension1.xml". This never was a problem, but it proved that this missing information causes the Excel crash when additionally using the "Visibility=1" setting. So this issue is solved, thank you for your offer to help!